# How to run multiple windows in cmd

Tags: github

Wondering if possible to run multiple windows in command script. I have a nose.js file that automates an online process and wish to run it once in cmd so it has multiple windows doing the same thing for efficiency purposes. Please help

Answer (score 1):

node.js runs via a command line (no windows involved). If you want to run more than one copy of the same program you can simply start it more that once.

Take this simple one:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/

Since it runs on a dedicated port (3000) if you start it more that once it will fail.

Here is something I found on google that details all the ways to do this:
https://itnext.io/4-solutions-to-run-multiple-node-js-or-npm-commands-simultaneously-9edaa6215a93